# Windows API - acces to battery, C#

Tags: c#, windows, api

I want to do a program with C# working with windows API.
The program has to access the Windows API to see the value of the battery and when the battery is 95% appear a message dialog with battery value.

I search info in Microsoft page but only I find battery class for Windows phone API
in this url (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.devices.power.battery.aspx#events)

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the function that you are after.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693(v=vs.85).aspx

Then you can just take what you need from the data that is returned.